# what's the reason of changes of copy function in UserDict.py

Tags: python, module

`copy` function defined by this:

```
def copy(self):
    if self.__class__ is UserDict:
        return UserDict(self.data.copy())
    import copy
    data = self.data
    //why use try? use return copy.copy(self) instead
    try:
        self.data = {}
        c = copy.copy(self)
    finally:
        self.data = data
    c.update(self)
    return c
```

why `try-finally` is used here? `self.data` will be cleared at first? what's the exception that will be raised here?

Comment: Interesting question. I can think of one exception that may be raised here -- memory not enough. This implementation seems indicating there're some cases programmers could change the content of `self.data` while executing `copy.copy(self)`. E.g. by overriding `__copy__`. And this implementation wants to prevent that, by firstly store `self.data` in another variable `data`. I also wonder what're the scenarios changing `self.data` is useful, and if a programmer really wants it what's the purpose to prevent it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore the `try` / `except`, the code is::

```
data = self.data
self.data = {}
c = copy.copy(self)
self.data = data
c.update(self)
```

Note the `self.data = {}` line. For some reason, the person who wrote this code felt that the copy would work better if `self.data` was set to an empty dictionary before calling `copy.copy()`, and then the actual data was copied  over using `update()`.

The point of the `finally` is to ensure that `self.data` is restored to its original value, no matter what happens in `copy.copy()`.